# Reactjs: error message does not show

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, materialize

I have a very simple React case where I have an error in the render function and nothing gets logged when the state gets updated to contain a bad value. When I check the generated source, the data-error property is getting updated so perhaps it is an issue with materializeCSS. No errors show in the console.

What am i doing wrong?

```
    var {ipcRenderer, remote} = require('electron');  
var mainProcess = remote.require("./main.js");
class YouTubeDownloaderForm extends React.Component 
    {
      constructor(props) 
      {
        super(props);
        this.state = 
        {
          url: '', 
          urlInvalid: false,
          urlsInformation:[]
        };
        this.handleAddClick = this.handleAddClick.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);      
        this.handleChangeClick = this.handleChangeClick.bind(this);
        this.handleUrlChange = this.handleUrlChange.bind(this);
        this.updateUrlInformation = this.updateUrlInformation.bind(this);
      }
      componentDidMount() 
      {
        ipcRenderer.on('UrlInformation', this.updateUrlInformation)
      } 
      componentWillUnmount() 
      {
        ipcRenderer.removeListener('UrlInformation', this.updateUrlInformation)
      }

      updateUrlInformation(event, arg) 
      {
        if(arg=== false)
        {
          this.setState({urlInvalid: true});
          return;
        }
        this.setState({urlInvalid: false});

        var urlsInformation = this.state.urlsInformation;
        urlsInformation.push(arg);
        this.setState({urlsInformation: urlsInformation});
        this.setState({url: ''});
      }

      handleAddClick(event) 
      {      
        mainProcess.getUrlInformation(this.state.url);
      }
      handleUrlChange(event) 
      {
        this.setState({url: event.target.value});
      }
      handleChangeClick(event) 
      {
      }
      handleSubmit(event) 
      {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
      render() 
      {
        return (
          <form className="col s12" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="input-field">
                <input id="Url" type="text" value={this.state.url} className="validate" onChange={this.handleUrlChange}></input> 
                <label id="UrlLabel" htmlFor="Url" data-error={this.state.urlInvalid===true?'The entered url seems to be invalid. ':''}>Url</label>                     
              </div>          
        </div>
        </form>
        );
      }
    }
    ReactDOM.render(<YouTubeDownloaderForm/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i was able to fix this by taking over the validation of the input field. Hope this helps someone.

i.e change

```
<input id="Url" type="text" value={this.state.url} className="validate" onChange={this.handleUrlChange}></input>
```

to

```
<input id="Url" type="text" value={this.state.url} className={this.state.urlInvalid===true?'invalid':''} onChange={this.handleUrlChange}></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where does the ipcRenderer variable comes from ?

Are you sure your JS console is empty ?

Maybe Error Boundaries can help you a bit, check https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html

Comment: Thanks @dfeyer. i had removed the ipcRenderer to show more compact code. i have added it back. The js console is empty. i will check the error boundaries or post this in the materialize css forums.